# She was so angry (that) she couldn't speak & There was such a lot of rain (that) we couldn’t go out

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

In the sentence "She was so angry that she couldn't speak", can I omit "that"?
Does "She was so angry she couldn't speak" sound natural to you?

In addition, in this sentence "There was such a lot of rain that we couldn’t go out", can I omit "that"?
Does "There was such a lot of rain we couldn’t go out" sound natural to you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can omit *that*.

In writing, I'd write it as this though

> She was so angry, she couldn't speak

In speaking, I'd have a short pause after angry

> She was so angry

1-2 second pause

> she couldn't speak

Comment: Thank you very much!In this sentence "What about "There was such a lot of rain that we couldn’t go out ", can I omit "that"? Does "What about "There was such a lot of rain we couldn’t go out " sound natural to you?

Comment: 2 second is way too long of a pause for that sentence. 1 second would add very strong emphasis. I would normally pause about 300 ms.

Comment: I'm not sure if the comma is valid there. I know for sure that using a comma before 'that' is ungrammatical – why would the rule change when 'that' is omitted?

Answer (score 3):

"such a lot of rain" sounds awkward.  I recommend

> It was raining so hard that we couldn't go out.

- *that* is optional.  You could replace it with a comma.
- *so much rain* would be a slight improvement over *such a lot of rain*.  However, *was raining so hard* better expresses the continuing weather condition at the time that the decision to stay inside was made.